# how to end properly my mouse logger program

Tags: c++, for-loop, winapi, mouseevent

my boss gave me this program to do in order to monitoring the "productivity" of my colleagues:
basically i have to log the mouse/cursor usage (the time when they are not using it etc..) of them.
so here is the code:

```
#include <windows.h>
int main(){
(.......)
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open(nomefile.c_str(),ios::app);

int count;
POINT curPos; 

for(;;)  *//start infinite cycle*
    {
            
        GetCursorPos(&curPos);          //legge la posizione del cursore
        float posX = curPos.x;          //restituisce la x del cursore
        Sleep(1000);                   //aspetta 1sec
        GetCursorPos(&curPos);          //legge la seconda posizione del cursore
        float curX = curPos.x;          //restituisce la seconda x del cursore 
        //controlla se il cursore è fermo
        if(posX == curX)
        {           
            count = count + 1;          //inizia a contare
        }
        else
        {
            if(count>30)
            {
                myfile << "\nsec: " << count;
           ////formatting sec/count in a readable form like hh:mm:ss///
                hour = count/3600;
                count = count%3600;
                min = count /60;
                count = count%60;
                sec = count;
                myfile << "time: " << time << "hh-mm-ss: " << hour << ":" << min << ":" << sec ;            
            }
        myfile << "_";
        count = 0;   
        myfile.flush();               //azzera contatore
        }
    
    }
myfile.close();
}
```

To summarize the code:

- #include win32api
- main(
- infinite cycle to check every second/count the cursor position
- if(count > 30) ---> print the time elapsed (but i put it in the else statement because i want it  to print only the last "count")
- else(reset count and write to file)
- restart cycle

so finally here is my question:
how can i close the program/terminal and write to the file the last count?? (if i kill/close the terminal while the cursor isn't moving, it doesn't write the last activity because i put the print/flush command in the else section(so in order to write it i must move the cursor to reset the count and print it)).

sorry guys i hope you understand my question(english is not my first language)

Comment: "my boss gave me this program to do in order to monitoring the "productivity" of my colleagues" That's a joke, right? This is really just an exercise for learning?

Comment: You need to have a stop condition in your "infinite" loop (e.g. `std::atomic_bool stop = false;`) and this condition must be changed by some external event. In Linux you could use [std::signal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal), but not sure if it works in windows. If nope, you can send the message to your app, either by standard input (that can be async oper to not block your main loop) or some sophisticated IPC.

Comment: After you finish this program, your next program will be one that randomly moves the mouse every few seconds. You can start by copying this program, and if it detects no mouse activity in some random interval between 15-60 seconds, move the mouse to random positions on the screen for a random interval of time, 1-7 seconds. Pick a random coordinate on the screen, then for the next 1-7 seconds move the mouse to a randomly chosen pixel to a randomly selected point within 0-70 pixels of the random coordinate. Then, 10% of the time, choose a longer period between mouse activities.

Comment: That would be murderous on the few surviving Word Perfect users where you can go days without touching a mouse.

Comment: @AndyG yeah...it's for learning  but also because i can't find a similar program. So i said "why  not try to do one myself".

Comment: @pptaszni "you can send the message to your app" yeah but i want it to be a logger so it would store the txts every day.

Comment: Using a polling loop is an inefficient way to implement this. Use [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) or the [Raw Input API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input) to hook the mouse, let the OS *notify* you when something happens. Then your app can simply wait for your exit condition (key press, window close, etc) and remove the hook at that time.

Comment: `1` Productive developers don't use a mouse unless it's absolutely, positively unavoidable. `2` The program classifies users that can move the mouse on a perfectly vertical line as lazy bums. `3` There's [SetCursorPos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcursorpos), rendering your approach useless. `4` A boss that cannot estimate the value of a developer by looking at their deliverables should seriously consider finding new challenges.

Comment: You can use multiple threads to control two functions, one function controls the acquisition of the current mouse coordinates, and the other thread communicates with the function through the condition variable, and ends the function after obtaining the end flag you set. Of course, I suggest you use `SetWindowsHookExW` function to realize the hook for the mouse.